# Show that the minor arcs are equal

Tags: geometry

Consider a $\Delta ABC$ whose Incenter is $I$. Show that when $AI$ is entended to meet the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at $E$, the two MINOR ARCS $BE$ and $CE$ are equal.

I cant actually approach the proof. Thanks.

Comment: Hei, any proof??

Answer (score 0):

The incenter is the intersection of angle bissectors.

Thus $AI$ bissects angle $A$ in two equal angles $(AB,AE)$ and $(AE,AC)$.

It is a classical result that equal inscribed angles in a circle subtend equal arcs

http://www.learnalberta.ca/content/memg/Division03/Inscribed%20Angle%20Property/index.html

Thus arc BE = arc EC.

Comment: Any direct solution instead of links and all?? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "and all" ?

Comment: Sorry. Can you provide a direct answer without the link? I couldn't find the answer in the wiki. Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the reference.

Comment: Sorry to interfere again, I dont think JeanMarie- you've understood the problem. Pl don't take this too rudely but I think so as you're providing links which actually doesn't contain my answer. Thanks.